# IF statement for a column

Tags: sql, function, if-statement, compare, case

I need to validate a column like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[VALIDATE_GENDER]()
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FLAG BIT
    /* IF ID_gender = 1 AND name_gender = 'Female' OR ID_gender = 2 AND
       name_gender = 'Male' THEN SET @FLAG = 1 
       ELSE
           SET @FLAG = 0 */
    RETURN @FLAG
END
GO
```

I tried with `CASE`, but to no avail:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[VALIDATE_GENDER]()
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FLAG BIT
    SELECT @FLAG = CASE WHEN (ID_gender = 1 AND name_gender = 'Female' 
    OR ID_gender = 2 AND name_gender = 'Male') THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END FROM GENDER
    RETURN @FLAG
END
GO
```

Please, could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: What kind of error you got?

Comment: You are setting a scalar value to the value of a column in a select statement. Flag will contain the value of the last row in your select statement. You didn't do any filtering or define an order so you have no way of knowing which rows value will be in your variable. Do you honestly have a table named Gender that has more than 2 rows?

Comment: @CJ The columns and table name are not recognized

Comment: It is extremely hard to answer your question because I don't know what exactly you need. The problem is not with the `CASE` but more probably your syntax and logic. In addition to that, like Sean said, your query may return more than 1 row and select @variable will only take the value of last row which I'm pretty sure it is not what you want.

Comment: @C.J. Thank you. What I want is the function to return true if ID = 1 and name_gender = 'Female' or ID = 2 and name_gender = 'Male' and return false if those statements are not met. I guess I'll try something else... maybe a trigger.